# Unable to record effects from Alesis Firewire 12 mixer

Tags: recording, sound-effects-recording, audio-interfaces, multichannel, aux-sends

I have [Alesis Firewire 12](http://www.alesis.com/multimix12firewire) mixer and I am successfully recording multi-channel tracks with Ableton Live (version 9) when I connect mixer and computer with firewire cable. However, if I mess up with effects on the mixer itself they are not recorded in Ableton tracks, instead tracks are clear and "raw".

Is it possible to record each channel's effects while recording multi-channel track in Ableton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://www.alesis.com/stuff/contentmgr/files/0/a7c78499380cd2f9a2af1084235fbcbc/file/mmfw12_16manual.pdf):

> The INDIVIDUAL channels sent to the computer send the signal after the
>   preamp gain knob, the high-pass filter, the three-band EQ, and the
>   channel fader.
>
> The effects of the AUX send knobs are NOT included in the outputs of
>   the individual channels.
>
> The MAIN mix channels sent to the computer exactly mirror the MAIN
>   output of the mixer. If you are only interested in making stereo
>   recordings, consider recording the MAIN channels in your recording
>   software.

So your only option is to crank up the effect return and let the master represent the combined effects mix.